# Will creating a user provided service on Cloudfoundry keep it online even if I shut down my computer?

Tags: service, cloud-foundry

I'm just confused on how CloudFoundry exactly works.

So if I create a service, will it be hosted on their cloud and I can expect it to run indefinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CloudFoundry will host your service and it will run as long as they are up, but to access it you must bind the service to an app.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of service in Cloud Foundry is quite open, it can refer to an app running in CF or outside, e.g. somewhere on the local network or on AWS or anywhere else.

I recently wrote a [blog entry](http://labs.bsb.com/2014/09/turn-a-legacy-app-into-a-cf-service/) about how you can turn an existing app into a CF service, you might find it useful.